# How to make a new rss feed by selecting entries from a rss feed by a criterion?

Tags: xml-parsing, rss

I want to select the entries from a [rss feed](https://www.science.org/action/showFeed?type=etoc&feed=rss&jc=science)  when the sub-tag of an item has a `<dc:type>Research Article</dc:type>` tag. Then select the items based on this criterion and make a new feed file which would be used by a feed reader (in my case newsboat).

I have tried to use xmlstarlet

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//dc:type[text()='Research Article']" -v ".*" -n rssfeed.xml
```

I have also tried a python code for this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def filter_rss_feed(input_file, output_file):
    tree = ET.parse(input_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    ns = {'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}

    for item in root.findall('.//item[not(dc:type[text()="Research Article"])]', ns):
        root.remove(item)

    tree.write(output_file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)

filter_rss_feed('rssfeed.xml', 'output_feed.xml')
```

But failed to achieve the goal. Is there a way to do this?

I want to generate a rssfeed like this
https://gist.github.com/ritajitk/33fd895e0c0fc7bd58051a4fa863bbfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to delete certain items - to select them you need to account for namespaces; you can use something something like

```
xml sel -N dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" -t -m "//_:item[.//dc:type[not(.='Research Article')]]" -v .  rssfeed.xml
```

EDIT:

To generate a new xml file which excludes the items to be deleted, try:

```
xml ed -N dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" -d "//_:item[.//dc:type[not(.='Research Article')]]"  rssfeed.xml > newfile.xml
```

Comment: This generates a plain text file. Is there a way to put it in a xml format so that I can point my rssreader to this file then the rssreader can take it from there?